Quarto presentation in R slide titels and table of contents
I have a quarto / revealjs presentation in R and like to fix my table of contents. Every (level 2) heading is translated into repeated bullet points in the TOC. How can I exclude some headings from the TOC? Or should I start new slides without heading?
---
title: "Presentation"
format: 
  revealjs:
    toc: true
    slide-number: true
editor: visual
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished presentation. To learn more about Quarto presentations see <https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/>.

## Quarto

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes:

-   Content authored with markdown
-   Output from executable code

## Quarto

When you click the **Render** button a presentation will be generated that includes both content and the output of embedded code. You can embed code like this:

```{r}
1 + 1
```



You can add the class .unlisted to remove it from the TOC, i.e.
## Quarto {.unlisted}

